# AdWords API PHP Issues

Tags: php, soap, google-ads-api

I am having some real problems figuring out what is wrong with my code for use with the Adwords API in php. I am trying to retrieve simple campaign stats for entering into a local database. However, I am unable to make this happen. I am using the examples from the initial download, however return a completely blank screen with no useful error messages at all. Below is my code, I'm hoping somebody here has run across this and can help me solve this.

```
    require_once 'Api/Ads/AdWords/Lib/AdWordsUser.php';
require_once 'Api/Ads/AdWords/Util/ReportUtils.php';

function GetCampaignStatsExample(AdWordsUser $user) {
    // Get the service, which loads the required classes.
    $campaignService = $user->GetService('CampaignService', ADWORDS_VERSION);

    // Create selector.
    $selector = new Selector();
    $selector->fields = array('Id', 'Name', 'Impressions', 'Clicks', 'Cost', 'Ctr');
    $selector->predicates[] = new Predicate('Impressions', 'GREATER_THAN', array(0));

    // Set date range to request stats for.
    $dateRange = new DateRange();
    $dateRange->min = date('Ymd', strtotime('-1 week'));
    $dateRange->max = date('Ymd', strtotime('-1 day'));
    $selector->dateRange = $dateRange;

    // Create paging controls.
    $selector->paging = new Paging(0, AdWordsConstants::RECOMMENDED_PAGE_SIZE);

    do {
        // Make the get request.
        $page = $campaignService->get($selector);

        // Display results.
        if (isset($page->entries)) {
            foreach ($page->entries as $campaign) {
                print_r("Campaign with name '%s' and id '%s' had the following stats " . "during the last week:\n", $campaign->name, $campaign->id);
                print_r("  Impressions: %d\n", $campaign->campaignStats->impressions);
                print_r("  Clicks: %d\n", $campaign->campaignStats->clicks);
                print_r("  Cost: $%.2f\n", $campaign->campaignStats->cost->microAmount / AdWordsConstants::MICROS_PER_DOLLAR);
                print_r("  CTR: %.2f%%\n", $campaign->campaignStats->ctr * 100);
            }
        } 
        else {
            print "No matching campaigns were found.\n";
        }

        // Advance the paging index.
        $selector->paging->startIndex += AdWordsConstants::RECOMMENDED_PAGE_SIZE;
    } 
    while ($page->totalNumEntries > $selector->paging->startIndex);
}

// Don't run the example if the file is being included.
if (__FILE__ != realpath($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) {
    return;
}

try {
    // Get AdWordsUser from credentials in "../auth.ini"
    // relative to the AdWordsUser.php file's directory.
    $user = new AdWordsUser();

    // Log every SOAP XML request and response.
    $user->LogAll();

    // Run the example.
    GetCampaignStatsExample($user);
} 
catch (OAuth2Exception $e) {
    ExampleUtils::CheckForOAuth2Errors($e);
} 
catch (ValidationException $e) {
    ExampleUtils::CheckForOAuth2Errors($e);
} 
catch (Exception $e) {
    print_r("An error has occurred: %s\n", $e->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this from the CLI.
Click start and run, (you get a black screen)
Type this into your command line interface.

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.exe -f "C:\wamp\www\AAAMYBUILD\timenow.php"
```

This will run the file if the first location is your php.exe file, and if this second location is the actual file you want to run.

You will see results in this window, never a browser.

It does seem that you should be able to run these files in a browser but I have never been able to do that either!

Answer (score 0):

It is because this example expects you to run it through a command line. If you want to run it in your browser you can remove the following part of your code:

```
// Don't run the example if the file is being included.
if (__FILE__ != realpath($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) {
    return;
}
```